# Using RMagick on Cuba keeps returning 0 as image width and height

Tags: ruby, image, rmagick

I'm writing an image cropper where I pass some crop area dimensions to a post request, download an image from a URL specified in the request body, and use RMagick to crop the image per specifications. Since I need to adjust the crop area to the image, I need image height and width, but when I try to access them, they are both 0.

```
require "open-uri"
require "RMagick"

img = Magick::Image.from_blob(open(params['image_url']).read).first
```

The problem is here - these two values are both zero with any image URL.

```
width = img.columns
height = img.rows
```

Here I attempt to crop the image according to the specified parameters passed in the post request and then write it into a file.

```
img.crop!(params['image_x'].to_f * width, params['image_y'].to_f * height, params['image_width'].to_f * width, params['image_height'].to_f * height, true)
img.write image_name
```

Everything else works fine - if I inspect the image, I get this:

JPEG 990x743 990x743+0+0 DirectClass 8-bit 78kb

Here's the [image](http://www.lovethesepics.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/12/Emperor-Penguin-Chick-Snow-Hill-Island-Antarctica.jpg). The result is the same with [other cute animal pictures](http://th09.deviantart.net/fs49/PRE/i/2009/167/6/d/jumping_spider_10_by_macrojunkie.jpg).

Comment: I don't speak Ruby, but us there some return value you can check after the `from_blob()` function call?

Comment: Turns out it was a problem because I don't really speak Ruby, either. I had a problem with types.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out what the problem was - it was nothing with RMagick and nothing I'd anticipated much. I'm new to Ruby so I guess I learned an important lesson about type safety. I didn't get console working with Cuba so I've been looking at the values by rendering them as a response onto the window. The values in the response body are all strings which obviously work unpredictably in mathematics. Things to take home from here:
a) No assuming types from now on - check to be sure.
b) I need to get my console working - there is no substitute, really.